# Como redirigir a una pages de un CarouselPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, carrusel

Tengo un CarouselPage por el que navego correctamente con los gestos del dedo. Pero necesito que dentro de un método me devuelva a la primera página del CarouselPage y no encuentro como hacerlo, tengo esto:

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CarouselPage carouselPage = new CarouselPage();
        carouselPage.Children.Add(new MainPage());
        carouselPage.Children.Add(new PhotoPage());



        MainPage = new NavigationPage(carouselPage);
        MainPage = new MainPage();
        MainPage = carouselPage;

    }
```

Ahora mismo hay dos paginas, MainPage() y PhotoPage()...cuando dentro de PhotoPage() tengo un método click y que me devuelva al inicio del carouselPage.

```
private async void ScanClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
       //Volver al MainPage.
    }
```

Gracias

Comment: Ya intentaste con carouselPage.Children.FirstOrDefault(); ?

Comment: No tengo el método FirstOrDefault() dentro de Children.

Comment: Agrega la referencia: using System.Linq; para que te aparezcan las extensiones de la propiedad Children. Saludos

Comment: Correcto he agregado el System.Linq y ya me aparece el Children.FirstOrDesault(); pero como debo usarlo exactamente para que me mueva el carrousel hasta la primera Page ?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto:

```
private async void ScanClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    //Volver al MainPage. Ejemplo 1

    MainPage.CurrentPage = carouselPage.Children.FirstOrDefault();

    //Si no quieres utilizar la referencia Linq intenta de esta manera.

    //Volver al MainPage. Ejemplo 2
    MainPage.CurrentPage = carouselPage.Children[0];
}
```

Comment: MainPage no contienen ningún método CurrentPage, he probado con carouselPage.CurrentPage = carouselPage.Children[0]; y con
            carouselPage.CurrentPage = carouselPage.Children.FirstOrDefault(); pero no funciona ninguno.

Comment: Sigo sin conseguir que funcione, alguien que me guíe hasta la solución? Siempre voto positivos a quien me ayuda

Comment: Podrías subir a github un ejemplo o tu código?. Así te puedo ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

En **PhotoPage.xaml.cs** tengo este metodo que scanea un codigo de barras y funciona ok:

```
private async void ScanClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var scan = new ZXingScannerPage(new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions() {             
 });

        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(scan);
        scan.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                qr = result.Text;
                MessagingCenter.Send(qr, "ChangeWebViewKey");

            });
        };

        App app = new App();
        app.HomeCarousel();

    }
```

Al final llamo a un metodo de la clase App que es donde me deberia devolver a la primera pagina del carousel.
**App.xaml.cs**

```
public void HomeCarousel()
    {
        //Volvemos a la primera Page del carousel
       // carouselPage.CurrentPage = carouselPage.Children[0];
        carouselPage.CurrentPage = carouselPage.Children.FirstOrDefault();

    }
```